# Radix Sort Branch prediction C++

Tags: c++, optimization, branch, cpu, prediction

I have written a simple radix sort but i am wondering about the high number of misses in branch prediction.

Here is the backbone of the Radix Sort

```
int i = 0;
do { bucket[getBucket()]++; } while(++i < n);

i = 1;
do { bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1]; } while(++i < BASEN);

i = n -1;
do { b[--bucket[getBucket()]] = a[i]; } while(--i >= 0);
```

n is the number of items, BASEN is the base (number of buckets).

It is standard for loops, I have just rewritten them to look nicer in assembly (they will only have 1 jump statement per loop).

It is the last of the three loops that is the big sinner, and the misses increases with the increase in n. And it seems that it is only the first time this loop is encountered.

Here comes the assambly for the last loop, they all look the same:

```
#NO_APP
        subl    $1, %r10d
        movslq  %r10d, %rax
        leaq    (%rsi,%rax,4), %rax
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L4:
        movl    (%rax), %esi
        andl    %r8d, %esi
        shrl    %cl, %esi
        movl    -120(%rsp,%rsi,4), %edi
        subl    $1, %edi
        movl    %edi, -120(%rsp,%rsi,4)
        movl    (%rax), %esi
        subq    $4, %rax
        subl    $1, %r10d
        movl    %esi, (%rdx,%rdi,4)
        jns     .L4
```

I would think it would be very easy for it to predict when to jump.

This is a run where n = 100000

Time Block: Time: 3712513 Instructions: 7205663 CacheFault: 1 BranchMispredictions: 337.

Here comes the full code:

```
#include "RadixSort.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


#define BASE 8
#define BASEN 256 // BASE ^ 2

RadixSort::RadixSort(int n) {
    b = new unsigned int[n];
}

RadixSort::~RadixSort() {}

unsigned int* RadixSort::start(unsigned int* a, unsigned int* b, int n, int mask, int shift) {
    #define getBucket() ((a[i] & mask) >> (shift * BASE))

    unsigned int bucket[BASEN] = { 0 };

    //asm(">> count buckets <<");
    int i = 0;
    do { bucket[getBucket()]++; } while(++i < n);

    //asm(">> add count prefix <<");
    i = 1;
    do { bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1]; } while(++i < BASEN);

    //asm(">> reorganize items <<");
    i = n -1;
    do { b[--bucket[getBucket()]] = a[i]; } while(--i >= 0);

    //asm(">> return items <<");
    return b;
}

unsigned int* RadixSort::Sort(unsigned int* a, int n) {
    unsigned shift = 0, mask = (unsigned int)pow(2, BASE) - 1;

    b = start(a, b, n, mask, shift);
    mask <<= BASE; shift++;
    a = start(b, a, n, mask, shift);
    mask <<= BASE; shift++;
    b = start(a, b, n, mask, shift);
    mask <<= BASE; shift++;
    a = start(b, a, n, mask, shift);

    return a;
}
```

Here is more detailed stat of the loops (n=100000):

```
Time Block: Time: 338752 Instructions: 700082 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 2951 Instructions: 1358 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 731609 Instructions: 1100179 CacheFault: 1 BranchMispredictions: 296

Time Block: Time: 338577 Instructions: 700082 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 2917 Instructions: 1358 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 608963 Instructions: 1100083 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 8

Time Block: Time: 338616 Instructions: 700082 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 2920 Instructions: 1358 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 595094 Instructions: 1100082 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5

Time Block: Time: 338611 Instructions: 700082 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 2957 Instructions: 1358 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
Time Block: Time: 591652 Instructions: 1100082 CacheFault: 0 BranchMispredictions: 5
```

It seems after the first run it learns

Comment: Did you measure 337 mispredictions just out of last 100k iterations loop, or over the entire program? Either way it seems really tiny

Comment: Can the optimization level be increased so that the address of a, b, bucket and the value for "i" are kept in regsiters? If so, I'm wondering if this would have any effect on the branc mispredictions.

Comment: It is optimized with O3. Yes I know it is low, but my logic tells me it should be even lower. It will encounter 12 for loops during the whole program it has to branch from (and actually all the branch mis prediction is from the third for loop, but only the first time), and for each for loop it will branch to the same label 100.000 times, and only branch out of it at the end, so I think it is a bit slow to figure out the correct direction, but it may just be me.

Comment: In any case, fixing the mispredictions will not speed up your program in a measurable way.